# How do I display data in a table using JavaScript and php?

Tags: php, node.js

What is the actual problem in this code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       var str="";

       <?php
       require 'dbcon.php';
       $query = "SELECT PatientID, HospitalRegistrationNo, FirstName, RegistrationDate,Gender FROM patientdemography";
       $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
       {?>
       str = "<tr><td><?php $row["PatientID"]?></td><td><?php $row["HospitalRegistrationNo"]?></td><td><?php $row["FirstName"]?><td><?php $row["RegistrationDate"]?> <td><?php $row["Gender"]?></td></tr>";
            //echo "".$row["PatientID"]." ".$row["HospitalRegistrationNo"]." ".$row["FirstName"]." ".$row["RegistrationDate"]." 
            //".$row["Gender"]."<br>";
            $('#tbpatientlist').append(str);
     } 

       });
</script>
```

Comment: Please update this thread, either accepting an answer or providing detail via comment or edit or even self answer why it doesnt answer your issue.

Answer (score 0):

For php, when printing a value to html please use either `echo $blah` or `print($blah)`, ALWAYS finish code statements with semi-colons `;` and your `while` loop doesnt look closed.

For example: `<?php $row["PatientID"]?>` becomes `<?php echo $row["PatientID"]; ?>`, and if opening a `<?php while(){ ?>` make sure the closing `}` is also inside `<?php ?>` tags too.

So, without seeing any more of your code, this looks like the cause. If not, please be clearer in what the expected output vs actual output is thanks. And also, you do need to include what youve already tried.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
       var str="";

       <?php
       require 'dbcon.php';
       $query = "SELECT PatientID, HospitalRegistrationNo, FirstName, RegistrationDate,Gender FROM patientdemography";
       $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
       {?>
       str = "<tr><td><?php echo $row["PatientID"]; ?></td><td><?php echo $row["HospitalRegistrationNo"]; ?></td><td><?php echo $row["FirstName"]; ?><td><?php echo $row["RegistrationDate"]; ?> <td><?php echo $row["Gender"]; ?></td></tr>";
            //echo "".$row["PatientID"]." ".$row["HospitalRegistrationNo"]." ".$row["FirstName"]." ".$row["RegistrationDate"]." 
            //".$row["Gender"]."<br>";
            $('#tbpatientlist').append(str);
       <?php } ?>


});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code many issues,

1) You did't `echo` PHP variable.
2) `<td>` not properly closed.
...

```
<?php
   require 'dbcon.php';
   $query = "SELECT PatientID, HospitalRegistrationNo, FirstName, RegistrationDate,Gender FROM patientdemography";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
   if (!empty($result)) {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var str = "";
        <?php
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
        ?>
            str += " <tr>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $row["PatientID"]; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $row["HospitalRegistrationNo"]; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $row["FirstName"]; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $row["RegistrationDate"]; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php $row["Gender"]?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>";
        <?php
            }
        ?>
        $('#tbpatientlist').append(str);
    });
</script>
<?php } ?>
```